# how to make jvm full gc in time

Tags: java, jvm, garbage-collection

We have a Java application whoes consuming memory is constantly increasing. But after executing jmap dump, the memory usage will soon falls back to the level at which it started.

We have used memory analysis tools but no memory leaks suspect have been found. However, this constant growth will cause HPA to continuously scale up the pod.

I want to make JVM automatically execute fullGC to reclaim all memory.

how can I make jvm execute full GC in time so that the memory used would not pile up.

We are using G1 garbage collector
and the param as followings:

```
-Dio.netty.allocator.type=unpooled
-Xms100m
-Xmx1900m
-XX:StartFlightRecording=settings=default
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000
-XX:NewRatio=1
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75
-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-XX:G1PeriodicGCInterval=60000
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary
-Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory=0
-Dio.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.maxDirectMemory=0
```

Comment: The "sawtooth" memory use is normal for JVMs. If it doesn't cause issues, don't worry about it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, But I seldom observed it trigger full GC itself, mostly it grow large and HPA would pull up lot of pod in Kubernetes, that is the problem.

Comment: If it's a problem, then just reduce the available memory. The JVM will happily use everything that you give it. If you give it less, it'll have to do a GC more often.

Answer (score 3):

> We have a Java application whoes consuming memory is constantly increasing.

Yes, this is called "sawtooth" memory use. **It's normal** - JVMs are designed to work this way.

If nothing in the system needs RAM, there is no actual need to free it until it is needed. JVMs spend in sum total fewer CPU cycles if they *do not* clean garbage (as in, actually free it) ASAP.

The JVM is a little computer-esque concept: It claims a chunk of RAM from the OS and then the JVM manages that memory on its own - your OS has a memory system (powered by `malloc` and `free` or similar) and the JVM has its own, built on top (the JVM just mallocs a huge chunk and then uses garbage collection to manage it).

It's not just 'saving an ignorably small amount of cycles' either; to actually return memory to the OS, it needs to return a contiguous chunk of it, and to do that, the JVM needs to move objects around which is expensive and requires locking or at least CAS behaviour to manage the effects of this in a multi-threaded environment (and as the GC runs on separate threads if that is faster, it's *always* a multi-threaded environment as far as GCing is concerned).

Hence, the JVM doesn't GC until there's a lot to GC. This results in sawtooth behaviour: Your JVM's memory usage goes up roughly linearly until it hits some threshold and then in a *very* short amount of time it goes steeply down, and then the process repeats.

Given that this is normal, "How do I make the JVM act like this" is not actually what you want - JVMs aren't designed to operate that way.

> We have used memory analysis tools but no memory leaks suspect have been found. However, this constant growth will cause HPA to continuously scale up the pod.

The problem is that your IAAS provider 'helpfully' put a cost on `malloc`. The JVM is operating under the assumption that if the OS lets you `malloc` new memory without any indication that this is problematic, the JVM will just do that instead of wasting cycles GCing prematurely.

However, your IAAS is actually letting you malloc but then ringing up the cash register to deal with the additional load. The `malloc` call that the JVM uses has no functionality to say: "You.. sure? It'll cost ya!" so the JVM has no idea it shouldn't.

**Hence, the general advice when running JVMs on environments where `malloc`ing new memory is problematic, due to it costing cash or having to steal it from other processes, that you use `-Xmx -Xms` to 'lock' in how much heap the JVM will use and avoid malloc/free cycles entirely**.

`-Xmx` sets the maximum heap it'll ever declare, and `-Xms` sets the minimum. Set it to the same and the JVM will alloc what it needs right away and never malloc/free for heap afterwards. Find the memory that the app runs properly under and pick those numbers.

There is a downside to this - you might *want* the JVM to scale (and thus, increase the costs to you) if e.g. more customers connect simultaneously. Unfortunately, JVMs just aren't good at that job. You can't tell a JVM: Grow as needed, but, you know, don't take memory you don't really need. It's a legitimate idea to want that, but, JVMs simply cannot do that, at least, no JVM implementations I know of work even remotely properly if you try to make it work like that.

You've got `-Xmx1900m` in your args list, so you're mostly already doing this. If this is more than you want to pay for, reduce it.

Note that `-Xmx` isn't the final word: The JVM also allocates 1 stack per active thread and these exist beyond the heap; it's whatever you pass to `-Xss` (which sets the stack size), multiplied by the max number of active threads; that goes *on top of* your `-Xmx`. Unless the java code that made the thread explicitly picks stack size, in which case it'll be that. Note that many earlier JVMs were bugged and would silently ignore any stack size specified that didn't evenly divide into some OS-enforced window size. JVMs also declare some more memory that it uses for itself instead of heap. So, if you pay $100,- a month for 2GB, but the costs go up to $400,- if you exceeds it, then `-Xmx1900m` is far too high. If you're trying to optimize, consider toying with `-Xss` and see how low you can make that without running into StackOverflowErrors.

Comment: Good answer. Please also note that setting -Xmx == -Xms turns off ergonomics (ie heap adaption). This might not be what you want. If you're going to mess with -Xss, do extensive testing. I've been severely bit by that.